# Why does moving a function to a default trait method introduce a borrowing error?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker

Given the struct `Foo` containing a collection of elements:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<i8>,
}
```

I have written a mutable view object intended to encapsulate a part of `Foo`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct View<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo,
}

impl<'a> View<'a> {
    fn iter(&'a self) -> std::slice::Iter<'a, i8> {
        self.foo.bar.iter()
    }

    fn iter_mut(&'a mut self) -> std::slice::IterMut<'a, i8> {
        self.foo.bar.iter_mut()
    }

    fn mutate(&'a mut self) {
        let mut vector: Vec<i8> = vec![];
        for value in self.iter().take(1).cloned() {
            vector.push(value);
        }
        for value in self.iter_mut() {
            *value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The `View` struct above works as intended and the following code prints `Foo { bar: [0, 0, 0] }`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { bar: vec![0, 1, 2] };
    let mut view = View { foo: &mut foo };
    view.mutate();
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

However, different kind of views should be possible — if `Foo` was a matrix, views could be rows, columns, or even submatrices. I have thus rewritten the `View` as a trait implemented by a struct, and given `mutate` a default implementation:

```rust
trait AbstractView<'a> {
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item = &'a i8>;
    type IteratorMut: Iterator<Item = &'a mut i8>;

    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::Iterator;
    fn iter_mut(&'a mut self) -> Self::IteratorMut;

    fn mutate(&'a mut self) {
        let mut vector: Vec<i8> = vec![];
        for value in self.iter().take(1).cloned() {
            vector.push(value);
        }
        for value in self.iter_mut() {
            *value = vector[0];
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct View<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo,
}

impl<'a> AbstractView<'a> for View<'a> {
    type Iterator = std::slice::Iter<'a, i8>;
    type IteratorMut = std::slice::IterMut<'a, i8>;

    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::Iterator {
        self.foo.bar.iter()
    }

    fn iter_mut(&'a mut self) -> Self::IteratorMut {
        self.foo.bar.iter_mut()
    }
}
```

This code does not compile succesfully, rustc complains about the call to `iter_mut` in `mutate`:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:22
   |
6  | trait AbstractView<'a> {
   |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
15 |         for value in self.iter().take(1).cloned() {
   |                      -----------
   |                      |
   |                      immutable borrow occurs here
   |                      argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
...
18 |         for value in self.iter_mut() {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Why does implementing `mutate` as a default method on the trait cause what looks like a different behaviour from the borrow checker? How can I get this trait to work?

[Example without the trait.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5580e3312126b8ffede7c93680f02300)

[Example with the trait.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5fab5167ed8060f3fafd591afe34d6cc)

Using rustc version 1.43.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to tell why the trait-based version doesn't work, but harder to say why the original *does* work.

It's all in the lifetimes. For the trait-based version, there's only a single lifetime `'a` everywhere. When we call `self.iter()` or `self.iter_mut()`, the borrow lasts for that same lifetime. That means we can't call both: if we call both, the immutable and mutable borrows have the same lifetime, so they exist simultaneously.

---

This raises the question of why the non-trait version works. Doesn't it do the exact same thing? The answer lies in the [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance) of the types `std::slice::Iter<'a, T>` and `std::slice::IterMut<'a, T>`. Variance of a generic type `T<'a>` is if and how `T<'a>` can be coerced to `T<'b>` when `'a` and `'b` are related.

For many types, this relationship is covariant: if `'a` is longer than `'b` (written `'a: 'b`) then values of type `T<'a>` can be coerced to values of type `T<'b>`. For some other types, the relationship is contravariant: if `'a: 'b`, then `T<'b>` can be coerced to `T<'a>` (an example of this is `Fn(&'a T)`). Finally, some types are invariant, so no coercion can occur.

`std::slice::Iter<'a, T>` is covariant in the lifetime `'a`. If `'a` is longer than `'b`, we can coerce to the shorter lifetime. That's exactly what's happening in your code. When we call `self.iter().take(1).cloned()`, `self.iter()` is actually coerced to a shorter `std::slice::Iter<'b, i8>` so that the mutable borrow can happen later.

```rust
fn mutate(&'a mut self) {
    let mut vector: Vec<i8> = vec![];
    // let iter = self.iter(); // works
    let mut iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, i8> = self.iter(); // doesn't work!
    for value in iter.take(1).cloned() {
        vector.push(value);
    }
    for value in self.iter_mut() {
        *value = vector[0];
    }
}
```

Using [the code above](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19931319f9933453050683bca99943b0), we get an error similar to your trait-based code.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:27:22
   |
11 | impl<'a> View<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
23 |         let iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, i8> = self.iter(); // doesn't work!
   |                   ------------------------   ---- immutable borrow occurs here
   |                   |
   |                   type annotation requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
...
27 |         for value in self.iter_mut() {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Incidently, `std::slice::IterMut<'a, T>` is *invariant* in its lifetime. This is because mutable references in general have to be invariant in order to be sound. This means that if you swapped the order of the mutable and immutable borrows, you'd get an error even in the non-trait version.

```rust
fn mutate(&'a mut self) {
    let mut vector: Vec<i8> = vec![];
    for value in self.iter_mut() {
        // This would panic if it compiled, of course
        *value = vector[0];
    }
    for value in self.iter().take(1).cloned() {
        vector.push(value);
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f76f5081e7fdf21c382af3d4eff137aa)

---

So the trait-based version doesn't work because `self.iter()` requires the borrow to last too long *and* it can't be coerced to a shorter borrow. In fact, with how things are written, it might not even make sense to have a shorter borrow. `Self::Iter` might only be defined for that one particular lifetime.

So what's the ideal way to write this? One way is to put the implementation of `mutate` in each implementation of `AbstractView`. When using the concrete types `Iter` and `IterMut`, the compiler knows that we can use covariance to make the lifetime shorter.

A more principled solution would be to make `Self::Iter` and `Self::IterMut` generic in their lifetimes so that the borrows can be shortened as needed. [Generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) like this aren't possible yet.

On the nightly compiler, it's possible to do this, though as the compiler rightly warns, generic associated types are not yet finished and may cause compiler crashes or bugs.

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<i8>,
}

trait AbstractView {
    type Iterator<'b>: Iterator<Item = &'b i8>;
    type IteratorMut<'b>: Iterator<Item = &'b mut i8>;

    // Eventually, these lifetimes should be elided
    // But it doesn't seem that that's implemented yet
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Iterator<'a>;
    fn iter_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Self::IteratorMut<'a>;

    fn mutate(&mut self) {
        let mut vector: Vec<i8> = vec![];
        for value in self.iter().take(1).cloned() {
            vector.push(value);
        }
        for value in self.iter_mut() {
            *value = vector[0];
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct View<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo,
}

impl<'a> AbstractView for View<'a> {
    type Iterator<'b> = std::slice::Iter<'b, i8>;
    type IteratorMut<'b> = std::slice::IterMut<'b, i8>;

    fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> Self::Iterator<'b> {
        self.foo.bar.iter()
    }

    fn iter_mut<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Self::IteratorMut<'b> {
        self.foo.bar.iter_mut()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { bar: vec![0, 1, 2] };
    let mut view = View { foo: &mut foo };
    view.mutate();
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7115534ac5d4b9c2b4cc0c4381cf485c)

Comment: Very insightful. So since the reusability of `mutate` depends on `Iterator` and `IteratorMut`, I won't be able to not duplicate the `mutate` function until the GAT become stable?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [SCappella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707040/12474293), I have understood and fixed my issue. Since I'd rather have a clean code base rather than an efficient one for my use case, I have replaced the iterators with vectors:

```rust
trait AbstractView {
    fn refs(&self) -> Vec<&i8>;
    fn refs_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut i8>;

    fn mutate(&mut self) {
        let mut vector: Vec<i8> = vec![];
        for value in self.refs().iter().take(1) {
            vector.push(**value);
        }
        for value in self.refs_mut() {
            *value = vector[0];
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
impl AbstractView for View<'_>
{
    fn refs(&self) -> Vec<&i8> {
        self.foo.bar.iter().collect()
    }

    fn refs_mut(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut i8> {
        self.foo.bar.iter_mut().collect()
    }
}
```

This lets me not duplicate the `mutate` method.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58f11bfc370a32b36e2282e73ca1b96f)